# How to show timestamps in Messages - Log?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Using the sql developer to compile packages is quite comfortable. I am happy, that sql developer shows me when he finished the compiling or if they are any errors.

[image: The Messages - Log Window]

But there is no timestamp and often enough, I whised, I had them. Any ideas how to enable this feature? I found nothing in the settings-window.

Comment: So you want to know when was the last time the package was recompiled?

Comment: No, thats not my question. I want to know, when the messages was written. Because there are more Messages but Success.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. You could [ask about it on the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)), and see if they might consider adding it in  future release.

Comment: @omeinusch Ok. I deleted my answer as I was addressing completely different requirement. AFAIK, I have not seen such feature in SQL Developer. For that matter, I haven't seen such feature neither inTOAD nor PL/SQL Developer. As Alex said, you could post a request for such feature if it really makes a good addition.